# How to limit one order per day for each user in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, limit

I need to limit users to purchase one order per day in woocommerce.
The woocommerce has limit order option.
when I set the limit option to 1, it works probably, but if user wants to edit order, he can not because when woocommerce starts edit an order, first create a new empty order in database, then after user ends the edition, woocommerce set last order as canceled and update new order.
As I set order limit to one, the empty order does not create, so the user cannot edit his order.

How can I force woocommerce to limit one order per day while users could edit that one order?

Comment: In your system does it is mandatory to do the login?

Comment: yes, they have to.

Comment: How about (somehow) inspecting the process of adding the new Order Details that Woocommerce uses and then replicating this process. Understand: An order is a Wordpress Post, so, when a user edits an order, you could use wc_get_order(  $order_id ) to get the Order post and using native Wordpress Post modification functions, you could possibly modify the Order. I know this is not an elegant solution - we still need to excavate Woocommerce's Order editing and creation process